# How to run function before 100px or less left when user scrolls down

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently using this one, however, it runs the function when user hit scroll at bottom exactly.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

run();

});

});
```

I want to run function (load more) when user scrolls down and 100px or less left in bottom. How can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($(this).scrollTop() === 100) { 
         run();
    });
});
```

First google next time. [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259132/jquery-scroll-function-after-100px)

Comment: And check your answer! Does it make sense?

Comment: If you find duplicates, close the question.

Comment: Also please take care to format your code examples properly to make them readable.

Comment: No, I mean, run if 100 px or less left at the bottom when scroll down.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 

  if($(window).scrollTop >= $(document).height() - 100) {
  run();
 });

});
```

Comment: If you find duplicates, close the question.

Comment: No, I mean, run if 100 px or less left at the bottom when scroll down.

Comment: Check (http://i.snag.gy/Nz86q.jpg) see the bottom, 100px or less if left. I want to run function when its like this.

Comment: @user198989 I edited my answer

Comment: Tried but it didnt run. I am using for whole page, not div. are you sure its correct ?