# Navigation Bar background disappears when page refreshes

Tags: jquery, css, function, scroll, nav

So right now I have a navbar that fades when it's at the top of the page and when you scroll it fades back in. This is fine, but when you refresh the page and the navbar is not at the top of the page, the navbar background is gone again because you need to scroll to trigger the function. Is there a way to accomplish the same thing without having to use a scroll event? Or a way to use scroll function but also keep the bar opacity at 1 when the page is refreshed and the navbar is not at the top of the page. Thank you in advance.

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var navbar = $(".navcontainer");
        $(window).scroll(function(){
           var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
           if (scrollPosition === 0){
              navbar.css("background-color", "rgba(32, 52, 74, 0");
           }else {
              navbar.css("background-color", "rgba(32, 52, 74, 1");
          }
       });
  });
```

CSS

```
.navcontainer{
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: background-color .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: The check is inside the `scroll` function, that's why it needs the scroll to trigger it. Try to make it a separate method and call the same from `ready` function as well as from `scroll`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259132/jquery-scroll-function-after-100px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to do this way. In this way you can reuse the method in page load as well as in scroll event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    checkHeaderStatus()
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        checkHeaderStatus()
    });
});

function checkHeaderStatus() {
    var navbar = $(".navcontainer");
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPosition === 0) {
        navbar.css("background-color", "rgba(32, 52, 74, 0");
    } else {
        navbar.css("background-color", "rgba(32, 52, 74, 1");
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Accept this answer please.